# ¿Puedo renderizar un archivo HTML dentro de un componente React?

Tags: html, jquery, reactjs

Mi caso es:

Tengo un archivo HTML que funciona perfectamente, con todos sus scripts, funciones... Mi problema es pasarlo a un componente React. Debido a eso, ¿Es posible importar este archivo al componente React, y renderizarlo en su vista mediante el método render()?

Sería algo asi:

```
import Prueba from './prueba.html'

export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div id="prueba"/>
        )
    }
}
render(Prueba, document.getElementById('prueba'));
```

¿Alguna sugerencia para solucionar este problema?

Comment: Te recomiendo que leas [esta respuesta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33980020/3791844)

Comment: igual esta puede servirte... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27934238/rendering-raw-html-with-reactjs

Answer (score 1):

puedes utilizar la propiedad [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html) para poder insertar un elemento html dentro de tu componente y/o tag.

**Ejemplo**

```js
import Prueba from './prueba.html'

var htmlContenido= { __html: Prueba };

export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div id="prueba" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={htmlContenido}/>
        )
    }
}
render(Prueba, document.getElementById('prueba'));
```

Espero te sirva, y sea lo que estabas buscando.